# Update where id=$id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query to submit data into the database:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET user='$user', name='$name' where id ='$id'";
```

the id will be obtained via url EX `localhost/index.php?id=123`

```
$id=$_GET['id']
```

The query will not work correctly; the data will not update.
If I write :

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET user='$user', name='$name' where id ='123'";
```

It works fine.

If I echo the ID it will show the correct result, `123`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: echo the whole sql query pls so we can see the real problem

Comment: This code screams SQL INJECTION!!! You should probably read up on what they are and how to prevent them.

Comment: Have a read of this question/answer - it explains the methods for avoiding SQL injection : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I'm quite sure your tablename and some columnnames are keywords, put them in inverted single qoutes: `UPDATE \`table\` SET \`user\`='$user', \`name\`='$name' WHERE \`id\` = $id`

Answer (score 12):

run ALL your queries the way you can get the error message along with erroneous query.
so, at least this way

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET user='$user', name='$name' where id ='$id'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

and it will tell you where is the problem.

It is WAY more convenient, precise and faster than asking questions here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing your problem is mal-formed SQL due to unescaped data interpolation - an SQL injection hole.

What does your actual generated query look like? Not the code that creates the sql (which you've got above), but the actual SQL **after** the variables are inserted?

I'm guessing it'll look something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET user='fred', name='O'Brien' where id='123';
                                     ^--unescaped quote
```

causing a syntax error.

If you're running the query like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

then change it to be

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

so you'll immediately get feedback if the query fails for any reason.

And then read up about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) holes

Comment: My comment on the original question does.

Comment: the result show this: 
UPDATE table SET user='robert', name='bob' where id="

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $_GET['id']

<form action="#.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id?>">
</form>
```

then, inside PHP block,

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE table SET user='$user', name='$name' where id ='$id'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the issue of how bad it is to pull data right from the GET array, I'd start by suggesting you properly escape your variables.  I assume ID is an integer, so there's no need for singlequotes around it.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET user='".$user."', name='".$name."' where id=".$id;
```

See if that works.

Comment: This will change absolutely NOTHING. `$x = "x $a x"` is treated exactly the same as `$x = 'x ' . $a . ' x';` by PHP. All you've done is rearrange the deck chairs on a sinking ship.

Comment: @MarcB He is talking about the single quotes being passed to the database engine.

Comment: @HaLeiVi: irrelevant. the `'` are inside a `"`-quoted string, so they're not quotes, they're just some random character as far as PHP is concerned.

Comment: @MarcB The error is not a php error. It is a database error. This $sql is being passed to the database which won't read the (") but will read the ('). And as nageeb rightly advised, a value surrounded by quotes is a string but the id field is expecting a number.

Comment: it's mysql. it autoconverts numbers as appropriate. `1 = '1'` is true in mysql (assuming strict mode is off)

Answer (score 0):

TableName should be there ....you have not used table name in your query..Echo the $sql and then try executing in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're wide open to SQL Injection attacks if you do it like this. Anyone can just alter the part after id= to anything they like and modify your database with that.

Secondly, I see you pass an id to the script, but where does it determine the `$user` and `$name` values? Seems like your code posted is incomplete.